# Tab in MFC windows application is not clickable

Tags: mfc

I have a strange problem about a MFC windows application in dual monitor system.
Let's say I have monitor A and monitor B.
If my window toolbar (start menu etc) is in monitor A and A is alsom my primary monitor. My application works fine. However, if A has toolbar while B is the primary monitor. When I move my application to window A, the tab is not clickable while other controls (buttons..)work.
I have no clue what's going on. Any suggesttions are appreciated..

Answer (score 1):

Finally I figured out the problem. To get the tab index, the code use last message position to get the click point and use HitTest to figure out which tab is clicked. In the multiple monitor system,  we should not use LOWORD and HIWORD as described below:

"Important  Do not use the LOWORD or HIWORD macros to extract the x- and y- coordinates of the cursor position because these macros return incorrect results on systems with multiple monitors. Systems with multiple monitors can have negative x- and y- coordinates, and LOWORD and HIWORD treat the coordinates as unsigned quantities."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644938(v=vs.85).aspx

After I use the  GET_X_LPARAM or GET_Y_LPARAM it works!